# Could you make this code more ideal using 'this' as many times as possible?

Tags: c++

```
 class Location 
{
int width, height;
public:
    Location(){width = height = 0;}
    Location(int w, int h)
    {width = w; height =h;}
void show();

 };
 void Location::show()
{
cout << width << height << endl;
}
```

The problem wants me to fix the code and make it more ideal using `this`.
But I don't know how to use `this` neither do I know how can using `this` make the code more ideal. It may seem a pretty dumb question to ask, but I'm still quite new at all these... can anyone help me understand this?

Comment: Create your assignment operator and there you can see one of the most important use of this to check for self assignment.

Answer (score 2):

You use `this` in this context to refer to the class member data. This means that you can change your constructor's parameter names to match the data members:

```
Location(int width, int height)
{
    this->width = width;
    this->height = height;
}
```

The function parameter names `with` and `height` have a closer scope than the class data members so `this` is used to refer to the latter.

Comment: I wouldn't say ambiguities - the compiler will always use the variable with the closest scope. Qualifying member variable names with `this` *allows* you to access them when identically-named variables (such as arguments) exist.

Comment: @tkhomas: thanks ;-) for some reason I thought I was in Java.

Comment: @AndrewMedico: I agree. My terminology was weak. Have changed.